# how to create oracle DSN?

Tags: oracle, odbc

I have tried downloading anything remotely resembling the oracle odbc drivers and still i am unable to generate a DSN to oracle.

I do not even see oracle drivers showing up in the odbc creation wizard!

All I see are drivers for SQL server and SQL native client.

how do I create a system DSN for oracle?

Comment: your correct, i meant to say DSN. updated question with the correction.

Comment: Did you install the drivers, or just download them? Are you using the [instant client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html) downloads, and for the right version of Windows (32/64-bit)?

Comment: im running things i downloaded that seems to be what i need on a x64 machine but still dont get anything. IE: nstant Client Package - ODBC: Additional libraries for enabling ODBC applications
Download instantclient-odbc-nt-11.2.0.3.0.zip (740,177 bytes)

Comment: instantclient-odbc-nt-11.2.0.3.0.zip (740,177 bytes)  << that's the 32 bit version.

Comment: What app are you using that needs the ODBC driver?  Is that app 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: 64 bit app. sql management studio.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the 32 or 64 bit ODBC Admin client.

A 64-bit version of the Microsoft Windows operating system includes the following versions of the Microsoft Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) Data Source Administrator tool (Odbcad32.exe):
The 32-bit version of the Odbcad32.exe file is located in the %systemdrive%\Windows\SysWoW64 folder.
The 64-bit version of the Odbcad32.exe file is located in the %systemdrive%\Windows\System32 folder.

See:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942976

Comment: i am in the odbc window and trying to create the DNS but don't see oracle as an option. I downloaded the drivers and edited the TNSNames.ora file and still nothing

Comment: Are you using 32 or 64 bit ODBC drivers?  The ODBC version needs to match the 32 or 64 bit of the Oracle client.  You need to use the right bit version of the ODBC Admin tool or you won't see the drivers.

Comment: i am using 64 because my machine is x64

Comment: Did you run:  The 64-bit version of the Odbcad32.exe file is located in the %systemdrive%\Windows\System32 folder.

Comment: running Odbcad32.exe bring up the wizard for adding a DNS, but oracle isn't listed there as an optional driver to use. just SQL server and SQL native client.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. did you ever get this resolved? If so, what did you do?